Why is my Unreal Engine physics asset behaving as if rotated by 90 degrees?
I'm writing a custom movement component and moving a custom skeletal mesh I made in blender using SafeMoveUpdatedComponent. Here is the main part of the code:
const FVector PositionDelta = CalculatePositionDelta(DeltaTime);
const FRotator RotationDelta = CalculateRotationDelta(DeltaTime);

const FQuat NewRotation = UpdatedComponent->GetComponentQuat() * FQuat(RotationDelta);

FHitResult Hit(1.0f);
SafeMoveUpdatedComponent(PositionDelta, NewRotation, true, Hit);

if (Hit.IsValidBlockingHit())
{
    HandleImpact(Hit, DeltaTime, PositionDelta);
    SlideAlongSurface(PositionDelta, 1.0f - Hit.Time, Hit.Normal, Hit, true);
}
UpdateComponentVelocity();

The collision behaves as if the physics asset of the mesh was rotated by 90 degrees, even though the debug Collision view shows that it's oriented correctly, the asset preview looks good as well. When I rotate it by additional 90 degrees then it works as it should, but clearly something is not ok.
You can see it going through a box here:

And here is how it collides when I rotate the main part of the physics asset by 90 degrees.

The same issue occurs when I use this mesh with Floating Pawn Movement component.
EDIT: I've managed to identify the source of the issue - the root bone of my skeletal mesh had 90 degree rotation applied on it. Leaving the question open, because the fundamental issue still isn't solved - if the root bone rotation is applied to the skeletal mesh why isn't it applied to the physics asset?

Since we speak about rotations and we have a 90 degree discrepancy, this very much smells like (sinX, cosX) being used as coordinates somewhere rather than (cosX, sinX), because cosX = sin(X + 90 degrees). I would check for any potential issues that may cause this first, before all else.

Please take a look at the update at the bottom of my question.

Wojtek, indeed, I have read that before writing a comment. But I wonder why(?) you have a 90 degree rotation. And this is why I think that it might be caused by some mixed up trigonometrical coordinates at some point.

The rotation on the root bone was due to me changing the Forward axis setting when exporting from Blender to UE.

But the physics asset itself is generated in unreal, and the preview for it shows it's aligned correctly with the mesh (also in the "simulate" preview) - the discrepancy appears only when using the physics asset with movement component.

The animation (pose) is calculated first, then physics applies a separate transformation over it.
A bone is a model's handle for the physics engine to use, but it doesn't go both ways.
Physics can move models but models have no way to calculate physics or affect the engine.
It's related to the bug where characters move around in T-pose, poking limbs through walls. The physics engine uses whatever it is given, even if there animation errors.

Why is it aligned with the mesh in the physics asset preview then? What makes the preview work correctly and the movement component not?

I can't say for sure, but that sounds like a bug. Preview might not have rendered your blender transform for some reason
